# Is there any way to explode a table inside query?

Tags: laravel

I have this table in my database.
» roles, and have content of 0,0,0,0,0,0

In this table i store user permissions. Example if he is an administrator it can be 0,0,0,0,0,1 or if he is an moderator and an administrator in the same time it can be 0,0,0,1,0,1.
But i don't know how i can show them in a query separated.

Example for administrator query only last parameter from that list 0,0,0,0,0,0.
So for it i have to do a explode in the query but i don't know how to do this.
I tried something like that to see if i can get the tables and explode it before query execute.

```
        $query = User::where(
    function($results) {
        dd($results);
        foreach($results as $result) {
            print($result);
        }
    })->first();
```

Someone have an idea how i can do this?

Comment: Would you please mention structure of your table for more clarification

Comment: @groovy_guy My table structure is an varchar(1000) with default values of 0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: and you want that one column (comma separated string) to be exploded into an array, right?

Comment: @groovy_guy Yes to make a global query with them in an array

Comment: I believe there could be simpler ways available to create your global query, It'll be useful if you can explain what exactly you are trying to achieve out of this or what is your global query

Comment: I want a query with where clause example for users have administrator (0,0,0,0,0,1), because last argument is administrator, but it can have more values (0,0,0,1,0,1), example so i can't use it static because i have to explode this

Comment: do you have only 6 items stored in that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a fixed pattern you can "explode" it easily.

for example:

```
$result = "0,0,0,0,0,1"; // your data in for is string so:
$permission = explode(",",$result); //  convert to an array.
```

// outpult is:

```
print ($permission);
```

## [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 ];

```
print ($permission[5]);
```

// output is:

## 1

now you can access each cell of the array.

but It's not a clear way to make permission and role.
I suggest you use the different tables with different relationships.

Comment: Yeah i know i can use this but i have to get all users with last parameter 1, i don't have a fixed pattern

Comment: do you have use where with "LIKE" condition?

Comment: for example:  select * from tables where permission LIKE "%,1"

Comment: No i dont use like condition

Comment: Thank you,i used LIKE now is working

Answer (score 0):

This might help  it will return permissions ending with 1

```
   User::where(function ($builder){       
     $builder->where('permission', 'regex','%1');           
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**as a simple and appropriate solution,
you can also write your, where condition as below**

```
->whereRaw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(permission_column_name, ',', 6), ',', -1) = 1")
```

as you can see in the above code,
With `SUBSTRING_INDEX(permission_column_name, ',', 6)` function we will be able to extract everything up to the sixth value in your column separated by a comma.

Because SUBSTRING_INDEX() function also allows us to use negative values to extract fields counting from the right, we are using this ability to extract the rightmost field containing the last value of string with `-1`.

using the same above method you can also find any value available at any position as required in the given comma-separated string in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each user has a role, you can add some methods to the `User` model to handle permissions.

```
Class User extends Authenticatable {
    private function getPermissions(): array {
        return explode(',', $this->role)
    }

    public function isAdministrator(): bool {
        $permissions = $this->getPermissions();

        return $permissions[5] == 1;
    }

    public function isModerator(): bool {
        $permissions = $this->getPermissions();

        return $permissions[3] == 1;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in your code. Like this:

```
$user = auth()->user() // Or User::find($id) ...
if ($user->isAdministrator() || $user->isModerator()) {
        // Do something
}
```